# Rolling updates without downtime using kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Scenario:

- I got 3 replicas of a service running
- I want to update its version

This is whats happening:

- The new container will be created
- As soon the container are switching their status from **ContainerCreation** to **Running** kubernetes will start terminating old versions of this container.

> Problem: Status **Running** does not make sure the application is available. How can I prevent kubernetes from terminating services **before** it is not sure the containers application is available? Maybe adding a necessary health check?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes runs [`readinessProbes`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes) to check if a container is actually up for accepting connections. This will be considered when performing a rolling update. While the [official Kubernetes documentation on this topic](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) is rather lengthy the blog post [Enable Rolling updates in Kubernetes with Zero downtime](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/enable-rolling-updates-in-kubernetes-with-zero-downtime-31d7ec388c81) is a nice summary. Maybe directly check the final deployment file at the end to get the idea.